# Web2py import modules

Tags: python, web2py

I have modules in the modules path in web2py
and to import those modules i just put

```
import mymodule
```

it works perfectly but **SOMETIME** and somehow it crushs and show an error saying

```
ImportError: No module named mymodule
```

i wanted to use `local_import` but it's no more supported in `Web2py` > `1.99.5`

to fix it i delete all `.pyc` in `web2py/gluon` then it works but sometime not

and even if everything work well, when i edit a module i must restart web2py to get the new modifaction!

Answer (score 2):

> ImportError: No module named mymodule

I think sometimes you get that error when there's an error in the imported module itself (i.e., it doesn't properly pass through the real error). Try importing and using the module from a standard Python shell and see if there's an error in the module that needs to be fixed.

> i wanted to use `local_import` but it's no more supported in `Web2py` > `1.99.5`

`local_import` should still work, it's just no longer the preferred method. If it doesn't work, please report it as a bug.

> when i edit a module i must restart web2py to get the new modifaction

Yes, that's how Python works. However, during development, you can have web2py automatically reload upon changes by doing the following:

```
from gluon.custom_import import track_changes; track_changes(True)
```

Comment: thanks! but the imported module contains no errors, i tryed to import it using only python, it works fine!

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Maybe ask on the web2py Google Group and/or report an issue on Google Code.